# SolrNet Hightlight only brings 1 field on result ( id ) - ignores field selection

Tags: c#, solrnet

I'm using SolrNet, managed to work on my upload process and manage to query the documents using either the panel ( admin ) or the application, the result is the same.
[Base Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSvIg.png)
The main results have the selected fields, but hightligth only has the id, no matter what I use on the field filter
[Results (15 fields)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70gc3.png)

[Highlight has only id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix0Te.png)

What possibly I might be missing?

Tried with named fields, wildcards, followed documentation, revised schema.

I was expecting a simple result, query finds the doc(s) I need, but hightlight also finds them but gives no field selection other than the id (in my case, `ct_id`)